# Parsing JSON response from VK API

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse the response from the method JSON vk api wall.get (sample response http://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=100172&count=5) and have problem

This is class for JSON structure

```
public class Wall implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public long from_id;
    public long to_id;
    public long date; 
    public String text;
    public long id;
    public String online;

    public static Wall parse(JSONObject o) throws JSONException {
        Wall wm = new Wall();
        wm.id = o.getLong("id");
        wm.from_id = o.getLong("from_id");
        wm.to_id = o.getLong("to_id");
        wm.date = o.getLong("date");
        wm.online = o.getString("online");
        wm.text = o.getString("text");
        return wm;
    }
```

and, this I try parse JSON response

```
protected ArrayList<Wall> parse(String source) throws JSONException{

        ArrayList<Wall> result = new ArrayList<Wall>();
        JSONObject js = new JSONObject(source);
        JSONArray response = new js.getJSONArray("items"); ///this throws exception
        for (int i=0; i< response.length(); i++){
            Wall wall = new Wall();
            JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject(i);
            wall.from_id = jo.getLong("from_id");
            wall.id = jo.getLong("id");
            wall.to_id = jo.getLong("to_id");
            wall.date = jo.getLong("date");
            wall.online = jo.getString("online");
            wall.text = jo.getString("text");
        }
        return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: whats the problem? you didn't post your problem. Also please post your logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json array name is `response` not `items`, use:

```
JSONArray response = new js.getJSONArray("response");
```

instead of:

```
JSONArray response = new js.getJSONArray("items");
```

And you are not adding your `wall` object to the `result`...

```
 for (int i=0; i< response.length(); i++){
        Wall wall = new Wall();
        JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject(i);
        wall.from_id = jo.getLong("from_id");
        wall.id = jo.getLong("id");
        wall.to_id = jo.getLong("to_id");
        wall.date = jo.getLong("date");
        wall.online = jo.getString("online");
        wall.text = jo.getString("text");
        result.add(wall);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this library it helped me in a web service response by json it's easy to use:

[GSON Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

[Easy guide to use GSON lib](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/use-gson-to-work-with-json-in-your-android-apps/1386)

Hope this helps you